# Preference for "==0" vs. "<1"

Tags: java, conventions

I've written a method in Java to determine whether a given year is a leap year or not. Here's the method as written:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear (int year) {
        return year <= 9999 && year > 0 && year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}
```

However, I noticed that IntelliJ originally corrected my redundant logic by replacing all of the instances of "== 0" with "< 1". I've since changed them back to "==0" in the above example.

Is there some preference for one over the other in terms of code simplicity or clarity? It seems like the simpler version is the "equals 0" as it is more precise than simply "less than 1."

Not sure if there's some convention on this, or if there's a reason why you'd prefer to use <1 over ==0 in any given case.

Thanks!

Comment: They aren't normally the same, since `-1 < 1` is true, but `-1 == 0` is false

Comment: @Matt they are the same here because the result from `%` will never be negative.

Comment: @Bohemian actually that is not correct, which is very annoying.  But they are the same here because of the `year > 0`

Comment: @Matt yes, I quaified my comment with "they are the same *here*" for that reason. Remainder is negative for negative operands, but year is never negative. `< 1` is a quirky way of saying `== 0` when negatives aren't possible.

Comment: Intellij must be out of its mind to fiddle with a computation like that. If I used it there would be a bug report.

Comment: Why the test involving 9999? That's not part of the definition of a leap year.

Comment: @user207421 I think it is obvious that it is to make sure the year won't be greater than or equal to 10000 years.

Comment: @Shizukura That's not 'why', that's 'what'. We know what it does. We don't know why it's there, where it doesn't belong.

Comment: @user207421 Apologies, I should have clarified that. There's a requirement that the year must be no longer than 4 digits.

Comment: That's not part of a leap year test.  Your method is called `isLeapYear()`, not `isValid()`. The range check for `> 0` and `<= 9999` should be in a prior validity check. Not here. Otherwise you can't detect invalid years at all: all you're telling yourself is that it isn't a leap year. Which in fact it might be. Leap years don't stop at 10,000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clarity is your guiding principle here: Go with `== 0` and `!= 0`.

The two options are *effectively* interchangeable, because in your case the remainder can't be less than zero, however `== 0` and `!= 0` are easier to read, and much closer to their natural langauge meaning of "has a remainder of zero" etc, and moreover it is the industry convention.

There is no "performance" difference.